# IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I have a client appication and a server using JBoss AS 7.1.1. On startup, my client connects to the server just fine and gives me a remote interface to use. However, when I try to run a function through the interface I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:GrahamsProjServer,modulename:GrahamsProjServer,distinctname:] 
combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@3a42f352
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
        at $Proxy0.persistSchemas(Unknown Source)
        at grahamsprojclient.main.GrahamsProjScreen.btnPersistActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at grahamsprojclient.main.GrahamsProjScreen.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at grahamsprojclient.main.GrahamsProjScreen$5.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

No error appears on the server. It looks as if it's not even talking to the server when I run the function. How could it be that on start up my client is connecting to the server just fine but when I try to run a function it won't connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `No EJB receiver available` message by itself doesn't say much as to why it won't connect, so this won't answer your question, but at least it might point you on the right direction.

The JBoss EJB client library uses `Log4j` so it won't print on `System.out` nor `System.err`. To actually know what's going on you have to enable logging on the `org.jboss.ejb.client` package, e.g. by including this line on your `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.jboss.ejb.client=TRACE
```

With this enabled you can better see what the client is doing for you and will most probably print the underlying error.

Also, as of JBoss 7.1.0, the `security-realm` comes enabled by default, so to make remote calls one must do one of the following:

- Disable it by removing the `<security-realm/>` from the `standalone.xml` file

OR

- Add users to the server by using the `bin/add-user(.bat)(.sh)` script. Once added, include the user/pwd info in your `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file.

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) you can find a more detailed guide as to how to make EJB calls from a remote client.

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout this trick here:

- go to **Jboss root folder ->standalone\deployments**
- Select your running module(.jar file and .deployed files and delete
  them
- Then go to your server and remove your module from the server and
  stop it.
- Then again add the project  and start the server.
- Then go and check your **Jboss root folder ->standalone\deployments**
  and check your deployed module is available there or not.If it it is
  there you are succeed.